# Do I put a question mark after the word do in this quote?

Tags: questions, quotation-marks

This is a quote by Franklin D Roosevelt, it goes as follows:

“ it is not sufficient just to want ask yourself. What are you going to do to get what you want”

My question is when writing this quote is it appropriate to put a ? after the word *do* in the quote.

Comment: Question marks are always used at the end of the question. https://www.grammarly.com/blog/question-mark/#2

Comment: You may have misunderstood the lines to mean: “It is not sufficient just to want. Ask yourself 'What are you going to do?' to get what you want.” That is not what the guy said or meant to say.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is almost certainly a misquote of << 'It isn't sufficient just to want – you've got to ask yourself what you are going to do to get the things you want.' >> [FDR] and is poorly formed. And as an indirect question, there shouldn't _be_ a question mark.

Comment: Grammarly gives the example << The chicken asked, “Why is everyone so concerned about where I’m walking?” >> The question mark comes _after_ 'about where I’m walking', as is the case with 'to get what you want'.

Comment: The answer is online. https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/505967-it-isn-t-sufficient-just-to-want---you-ve-got-to

Answer (score 1):

General answer on quotations:

Question marks and other punctuation should be exactly as published (print or online). If for some reason there was not a question mark at the end of a question in a published quotation, then don't add one unless you indicate that it was an editorial addition. The way of doing this depends on the style guide you are following.

If you are transcribing a speech or other oral communication (not written down), then you have to decide what is correct punctuation, which includes putting question marks at the end of questions.

*Are you insane?* is a question.

*I question whether you are insane.* is not a question.

The transcribing of speech is a complex issue. I recommend consulting a style guide, such as *Chicago Manual of Style*, *AP Stylebook*, Strunk and White's *Elements of Style*, and others to learn about this area of writing.